# how to rename files while copying?

Tags: bash, shell, rename, file-copy

How would I copy (archive style where date isn't changed) all the files in a backup directory to the user's directory while renaming each file to remove the random string portion from the name (i.e., -2b0fd460_1426b77b1ee_-7b8e)?

cp from:

```
/backup/path/data/Erp.2014.02.16_16.57.03-2b0fd460_1426b77b1ee_-7b8e.etf
```

to:

```
/home/user/data/Erp.2014.02.16_16.57.03.etf
```

Each file will always start with "Erp." followed by the date-time stamp string followed by the random string and then the extension ".etf". I want to keep all name elements including the date-time stamp. I just want to remove the random string.

The random string allows multiple backups of the same file. However, in this case, I just ran fdupes and there are no duplicates. So I can simply restore all the files, removing the random string.

I'm looking for a one-line bash command to do it.

If that won't work, I could do it in two or more steps. I normally use KRename, but in this case I need to do it in bash. (I'm working remotely.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pax` can do this all at once. You could do:

```
cd /backup/path/data && pax -wrs'/-.*$/.etf/' Erp*etf /home/user/data
```

`pax` preserves times by default, but can add `-pe` to preserve everything (best done as root) or `-pp` to preserve permissions , eg:

```
cd /backup/path/data && pax -wrs'/-.*$/.etf/' -pe Erp*etf /home/user/data
```

Otherwise (`pax` isn't usually available by default), surely it is better to do a copy then a `rename`:

```
cp -a /backup/path/data/Erp*.etf /home/user/data
rename 's/-.*$/.etf/' /home/user/data/Erp*.etf
```

This way there is not a different process started for each file.

Comment: I can see that I need to become familiar with `pax`. This looks like a very useful tool. Makes me wonder why it isn't standard in more distros...

Comment: @MountainX, Good question, according to Wikipedia, `pax` has been in the Linux Standard Base since 2005. Plus the would be alternative for this, GNU `cpio`, is possibly the least featureful GNU tool in existence.

Comment: +1 for your last solution and *This way there is not a different process started for each file.* **But** `rename` is different on Fedora/Red Hat: I don’t know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `cp` command with the `-a` option

```
-a, --archive
       same as -dR --preserve=all
```

And then use a for loop to rename all files while copying them:

```
for file in Erp*etf; do
  cp -a $file destinationDirectory/${file%%-*}.etf
done
```

Ready. Start this command in the source directory.

**Explanation:** The `%%-*` will cut off all the characters after the first occurence of a hyphen/minus `-` and the `.etf` at the end again adds the file extension.

Well, and as a one liner, put it all in one line. :-) Like this

```
for file in Erp*etf; do cp -a $file destinationDirectory/${file%%-*}.etf; done
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please quote the documentation for the `%%-*` tip? I'm curious.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh, use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). Put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

Then use

```
zcp '/backup/path/data/(*)-[0-9A-Fa-f_]#.(*)' '/home/user/data/$1$2'
```

In bash:

```
zsh -c 'autoload zmv; zmv -C $0 $1' '/backup/path/data/(*)-[0-9A-Fa-f_]#.(*)' '/home/user/data/$1$2'
```

If you don't have zsh, a POSIX way [uses pax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115879) (this copies directories recursively).

If you're on a restricted system with no zsh and no pax, you can use a loop:

```
for source in /backup/path/data/*-*.etf; do
  basename=${source##*/}
  cp "$source" "/home/user/data/${basename%-*}.${basename##*.}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`cp` doesn't have that capability.  I recall `cpio` being able to do that, but the current manpage says otherwise.  However, (gnu) `tar` does have a `--transform` option:

```
 --transform, --xform EXPRESSION
       use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names
```

So you'd have a cmdline like:

```
(cd /backup/path/data; tar --create --transform 's/-.*-....//' .) | (cd /home/user/data; tar --extract)
```